# What does "perf stat" output mean?

Tags: performance, perf

I use "`perf stat`" command to do a statistic of some events:

```
[root@root test]# perf stat -a -e "r81d0","r82d0" -v ./a
r81d0: 71800964 1269047979 1269006431
r82d0: 26655201 1284214869 1284214869

 Performance counter stats for './a':

        71,800,964 r81d0                                                        [100.00%]
        26,655,201 r82d0

       0.036892349 seconds time elapsed
```

(1) I know `71800964` is the count of "`r81d0`", but what is the meaning of `1269047979` and `1269006431`?
(2) What is the meaning of "`[100.00%]`"?

I have tried to "`perf stat --help`", but can't get the explanations of these values.

Comment: is giving `-v` necessary in your use case?

Comment: @Miline:No, but I want to know the meanings of output.

Comment: Nan Xiao, what is the difference of output between `perf stat -r 3 -a -e "r81d0","r82d0" -v ./a` and reordered events: `perf stat -r 3 -a -e "r82d0","r81d0" -v ./a`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[root@root test]# perf stat -a -e "r81d0","r82d0" -v ./a
r81d0: 71800964 1269047979 1269006431
r82d0: 26655201 1284214869 1284214869
```

This is output from verbose option, as defined in [tools/perf/builtin-stat.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/builtin-stat.c?v=3.18) file of the kernel:

```
391 /*
392  * Read out the results of a single counter:
393  * aggregate counts across CPUs in system-wide mode
394  */
395 static int read_counter_aggr(struct perf_evsel *counter)

408         if (verbose) {
409                 fprintf(output, "%s: %" PRIu64 " %" PRIu64 " %" PRIu64 "\n",
410                         perf_evsel__name(counter), count[0], count[1], count[2]);
411         }
```

count is from `struct perf_counts_values`, defined as http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/util/evsel.h?v=3.18#L12 with array of three uint64_t values, named as `val`, `ena`, `run`

Three `count` values are filled by kernel and are read from fd, opened with `perf_event_open()` syscall. There is related part of `man perf_event_open`: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html

```
   read_format
          This field specifies the format of the data returned by
          read(2) on a perf_event_open() file descriptor.

          PERF_FORMAT_TOTAL_TIME_ENABLED
                 Adds the 64-bit time_enabled field.  This can be used
                 to calculate estimated totals if the PMU is
                 overcommitted and multiplexing is happening.

          PERF_FORMAT_TOTAL_TIME_RUNNING
                 Adds the 64-bit time_running field.  This can be used
                 to calculate estimated totals if the PMU is
                 overcommitted and multiplexing is happening.  ...
```

`perf stat` [enables all TIME flags](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/builtin-stat.c?v=3.18#L294) if `scale` is true -

```
298         if (scale)
299                 attr->read_format = PERF_FORMAT_TOTAL_TIME_ENABLED |
300                                     PERF_FORMAT_TOTAL_TIME_RUNNING;
```

So, first counter is raw event count; second is proportional to the time when this event was collected and last is proportional to the total running time. This is needed when you asks `perf` to stat on high number of events, which can't be monitored at once (hardware usually has up to 5-7 performance monitors). In such case in-kernel perf will run subsets of required event for some parts of execution; and subsets will be changed several times. With `ena` and `run` counts, perf can estimate how inaccurate event monitoring was in case of multiplexing.

```
 Performance counter stats for './a':

    71,800,964 r81d0                                            [100.00%]
    26,655,201 r82d0
```

And in your case two events were mapped in the same time without needs of multiplexing; your `ena` and `run` counters are close. And [`print_aggr`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/builtin-stat.c?v=3.18#L1117) function prints their ratio:

```
1137                                 val += counter->counts->cpu[cpu].val;
1138                                 ena += counter->counts->cpu[cpu].ena;
1139                                 run += counter->counts->cpu[cpu].run;
```

Print_noise will output in case of `-r N` option to rerun task N times to get statistics (man: *`--repeat=<n>` repeat command and print average + stddev (max: 100)*)

```
1176                                 print_noise(counter, 1.0);
```

And there is `[100.00%]` printer:

```
1178                                 if (run != ena)
1179                                         fprintf(output, "  (%.2f%%)",
1180                                                 100.0 * run / ena);
```

It will not print 100% if both run and ena times are equal, and your r82d0 event have equal. Your r81d0 event have slightly different run and ena, so 100% is printed in one line.

I know that `perf stat -d` can be inaccurate, because it asks for too much events; and there will be not 100% mulitplexing, but something like 53%. It means "this event was counted only in 53% of the program runtime in some random parts of it"; and if you program have several separated computing stages, events with low run/ena ratio will be less accurate.

Comment: Some info about perf event overcommit multiplexing "perf_events status update" (2010) http://cscads.rice.edu/workshops/summer-2010/slides/performance-tools/perf_events_status_update.pdf  - from slide 11 Event grouping. Event sets (groups) are changed on every scheduler tick (100-250-300-1000 times per second?). Advanced multiplexing changing with hrtimer from 3.11: http://www.paradyn.org/CSCADS2013/slides/eranian13.pdf (2013) - slide 8. http://rts.lab.asu.edu/web_438/project_final/CSE_598_Performance_Monitoring_Unit.pdf - page 6 for limitation of multiplexing