# Is it possible to raise the sampling frequency of perf stat?

Tags: perf

I am using `perf` for profiling, but the number of monitored PMU events is higher than the number of the hardware counters, so round-robin multiplexing strategy is triggered. However, some of my test cases may run less than a millisecond, which means that if the execution time is less than the multiplicative inverse of the default switch frequency (1000Hz), some events may not be profiled.

How to raise the sampling frequency of `perf stat` like `perf record -F <freqency>` to make sure that every events will be recorded even if the measurement overhead may slightly increase?

Answer (score 4):

First off, remember that **sampling** is different than **counting**.

`perf record` will invariably do a **sampling** of all the events that occured during the time period of profiling. This means that it will not count all of the events that happened (this can be tweaked of course!). You can modify the frequency of sample collection to increase the number of samples that get collected. It will usually be like for every 10 (or whatever number > 0) events that occur, `perf record` will only record 1 of them.

`perf stat` will do a **counting** of all the events that occur. For each event that happens, `perf stat` will count it and will try not to miss any, unlike **sampling**. Of course, the number of events counted may not be accurate if there is multiplexing involved (i.e. when the number of events measured is greater than the number of available hardware counters). There is no concept of setting up frequencies in `perf stat` since all it does is a direct **count** of all the events that you intend to measure.

This is the [proof](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/tools/perf/builtin-stat.c#L227) from the linux kernel source code :-

You can see it sets up sample period (the inverse of sample freq) to be 0 - so you know what sample freq is ;)

Anyway, what you can do is a verbose reading of `perf stat` using `perf stat -v` to see and understand what is happening with all of the events that you are measuring.

To understand more about `perf stat`, you can also read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958392/what-does-perf-stat-output-mean).